# System bars (status bar, navigation bar) blink white when shown after being hidden

Tags: android

On Tablet:
[image: recorded error]

On Phone landscape:
[image: recorded error]

[Sample project](https://github.com/deepsorrow/StatusBarTest):

```
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.show).setOnClickListener {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window?.insetsController?.let {
                window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)
                window.insetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
            }
        } else {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 0
        }
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.hide).setOnClickListener {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window?.insetsController?.let {
                window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
                it.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                it.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
            }
        } else {
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        }
    }
```

It happens both on API >= 30 (Android 11) and API <= 29 (Android 10). Am I missing something? :(